# Open-source LDAP integration for Docker Registry

Tags: ldap

My company runs using [OpenLDAP](https://www.openldap.org/) as centralized service to control users, roles and groups. We want to have a private [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) for internal usage, and we want to integrate it with our LDAP instance.

We know there are some commercial and open-source solutions. **Is there any lightweight open-source solution to easily integrate Docker Registry with OpenLDAP?**

Thank you.

Comment: How about setting up [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) before your LDAP? Keycloak is an ouath2 authentication provider, with ldap backend support. So the docker registry would see an oauth authentification, which is already [supported](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/oauth/). Users would have also a nice UI for password/account settings. Although I would not call this a leightweight.

Comment: Login would work so: 1. docker client contacts keycloak, user enters login/password 2. keycloak gives back a token 3. docker client contacts registry with this token 4. registry contacts keycloak and asks if the token is valid, and for who. Nice thing is that this token is re-generated on every login, it is essentially a cookie, and no one can see a password.